# Converting complex StructType to MapType

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I transform datafame field into MapType from a StructType field where only not null StructFields are presented?
Consider the following dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ('Joe', 'Doe', (('Alice', 40), ('Bob', 50), None)),
    ('Jack', 'Jackson', (('Alice', 40), None, None)), 
    ('John', 'Johnson', (None, None, None)), 
])
schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('surname', StringType(), True),
    StructField('friends', StructType([
        StructField('some_friend_id_01', StructType([
            StructField('name', StringType(), True),
            StructField('age', LongType(), True),
        ]), True),
        StructField('some_friend_id_02', StructType([
            StructField('name', StringType(), True),
            StructField('age', LongType(), True),
        ]), True),
        StructField('some_friend_id_03', StructType([
            StructField('name', StringType(), True),
            StructField('age', LongType(), True),
        ]), True),
        # some many more StructFields...
    ]), True),
])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

The dataframe rows look like this:

```
Row(name='Joe', surname='Doe', friends=Row(some_friend_id_01=Row(name='Alice', age=40), some_friend_id_02=Row(name='Bob', age=50), some_friend_id_03=None))
```

I need to convert the dataframe to follow the schema, which looks like this:

```
target_schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('surname', StringType(), True),
    StructField('friends', MapType(StringType(), StructType([
        StructField('name', StringType(), True),
        StructField('age', LongType(), True),
    ]), True), True),
])
```

And the final dataframe to be:

```
[
  Row(name='Joe', surname='Doe', friends={'some_friend_id_02': Row(name='Bob', age=50), 'some_friend_id_01': Row(name='Alice', age=40)}),
  Row(name='Jack', surname='Jackson', friends={'some_friend_id_01': Row(name='Alice', age=40)}),
  Row(name='John', surname='Johnson', friends=None)
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the schema using `to_json` and `from_json`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select(
    F.from_json(
        F.to_json(F.struct(*df.columns)), 
        target_schema
    ).alias('col')
).select('col.*')

df2.show(truncate=False)
+----+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name|surname|friends                                                           |
+----+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Joe |Doe    |[some_friend_id_01 -> [Alice, 40], some_friend_id_02 -> [Bob, 50]]|
|Jack|Jackson|[some_friend_id_01 -> [Alice, 40]]                                |
|John|Johnson|[]                                                                |
+----+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This solution works great. Does it make sense (performance-wise) to run `from_json` and `to_json` on affected columns only instead of all columns?

Comment: Yeah, you can do it on the affected columns only, but then you'll need to change `target_schema`